# Hyperledger Fabric (Java): EOF Error in Orderer while attempting to Update Channel Config via Fabric-SDK

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric

I'm attempting to utilize the Fabric-SDK-Java (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java) in a custom client application (works with an admin role user in the wallet) to update an existing channel's channel configuration. My expectation was for:

#1) the channel configuration file to be retrieved from the ledger (Done by SDK)

#2) the file to be converted from .pb to .json (Done by SDK)

#3) the file to be modified by me (Done by custom client code)

#4) add the peer signatures for member orgs of the channel to the transaction (Done by SDK)

#5) have the orderer process the transaction into a block and submit it to the peers' ledger

Problem:
At step 5, I get an error in my client code console:

`Channel mychannel orderer localhost:7050 status returned failure code 400 (BAD_REQUEST) during orderer next`

In the orderer's log, I get the following at WARN level:

```
Rejecting broadcast of config message from <ip> because of error: error applying config update to existing channel 'mychannel': error authorizing update: unexpected EOF
```

What I've attempted so far is to reduce my channel down to just 1 admin org and the orderer for testing, pull down the pb file of the channel config for my channel and convert it to json via the terminal commands (via step 1 of https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/config_update.html) and remove all header info using the jq tool, modify that json manually in a text editor, and the use the following code to update the channel:

```
Channel myChannel = network.getChannel()
String msg = ... //obtains the channel config json file from a directory
UpdateChannelConfiguration ucc = new UpdateChannelConfiguration();
ucc.setUpdateChanneConfiguration(msg.getBytes());
myChannel.updateChannelConfiguration(ucc, myChannel.getUpdateChannelConfigurationSignature(ucc, user)); //where the user is an object implementing the User interface taking in a: username, mspId, Enrollment object, and admin role in a Set
```

My questions are:

#1) What is the meaning and cause of the EOF error?

#2) Is the channel config json file that was converted from the .pb file (with headers removed) the correct file to add to the "setUpdateChanneConfiguration" method after I modify it with my updates?

#3) Do I have to manually change the version field in the modified sections of the channel config json file or will the method take care of that automatically?

#4) Do I need the orderer signature along with the admin org peer signature on the update transaction (via the getUpdateChannelConfigurationSignature method)? (attempted this but didnt have any effect on the error)

Answer (score 0):

1. EOF error means you have a wrong format for the configuration file you submitted. Based on your question, I think you submitted the JSON instead of pb file right?
2. No. After you modify it, you will have to re-encode the JSON to pb before submitting to orderer. Check the Step 3 in [this documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/config_update.html).
3. No, don't change it manually.
4. No, please follow the documentation provided above.

One thing to note. Better not to use the SDK for this, as what mentioned in the documentation:

> The Fabric v2.x SDKs only support transaction and query functions and event listening. Support for administrative functions for channels and nodes has been removed from the SDKs in favor of the CLI tools.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response. I attempted to utilize a modified config pb file after my question submission and ended up getting the error "proto: can't skip unknown wire type 7" in the orderer logs. Would you happen to know the cause? Unfortunately I don't see much documentation on this type of error's actual meaning.

Comment: Should be your proto format problem. I mean the fields included in the proto file are not complete, make sure you add back the header after modification. That should be another thread, you should close this if I answered your questions.